# Access form link three listbox on the same form using the same table based on category

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a question about how to link a selected item on one listbox and to display on the other listbox in the same form... this is what i want to :

I have a table called category which has the following values:

```
category table:
categorynumber (primary key) int not null,
categoryname varchar() not null,
Parentcategory (foreign key refering to categorynumber)int not null,
categoryfollowingnumber int not null.
```

I want to select from category, subcategory and subsubcategory. Thus

```
listbox1(category1),
listbox2(subcategory based on category1)
listbox3 (sub-sub category based on subcategory)

listbox1: select category: Car
listbox2: display: toyota
listbox3: display: toyota corola
```

I can see category1 in listbox1, but the link based on the selected category is where I get stuck. Do I have to use a subform or this possible on a single form ?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @djadmin..yes i did up to now, first i used the following steps: i created three list box in a form; in listbox1 rowResource: i query all the main category ( it works, i see only the main category as i wanted). Then on listbox1 event afterupdate i used the following code to display the subcategory in the listbox2: Me.listbox2.Rowsource = Me.listbox1.Rowsource followed by Me.listbox2.Requery...... but i cant see anything on the listbox2, i guess if i can fix to see the subcategry on the listbox2 then i can see also on the listbox3.. all value is in one table within a FK and PK. thx..luis

Answer (score 1):

You will need something like this for your row sources:

```
 Listbox1: SELECT id, category FROM categorytable
 Listbox2: SELECT id, subcategory FROM subcategorytable
           WHERE categoryID = Forms!NameOfForm!LListbox1
 Listbox3: SELECT id, subsubcategory FROM subsubcategorytable
           WHERE subcategoryID = Forms!NameOfForm!LListbox2
```

In both the current event for the form and the after update event for listbox1 and listbox2, you will need to requery listbox2 and listbox3 as appropriate.